# Unable to connect to ElasticSearch docker container from the transport client in another docker container

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, playframework, elasticsearch-java-api

I started elasticsearch docker container using:

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4
```

then I tried to link another docker container which actually uses the transport client (same version - 6.2.4) to access the elasticsearch container using:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 --link 57b2dc1f05b3:elasticsearch <container_name>
```

I got the following error message:

```
node {#transport#-1}{zPkzTwpJRNmzGiEM8MOQQA}{elasticsearch}{172.17.0.2:9300} not part of the cluster Cluster [elasticsearch-cluster], ignoring...
[error] application -

! @7832clj69 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/create-question-index] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{zPkzTwpJRNmzGiEM8MOQQA}{elasticsearch}{172.17.0.2:9300}]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:261) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:191) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:179) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:212) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:94) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:162) [com.typesafe.play.play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:159) [com.typesafe.play.play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:216) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{zPkzTwpJRNmzGiEM8MOQQA}{elasticsearch}{172.17.0.2:9300}]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:347) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:245) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:60) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:371) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:405) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:394) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.execute(AbstractClient.java:1247) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:46) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.get(ActionRequestBuilder.java:53) ~[org.elasticsearch.elasticsearch-6.2.4.jar:6.2.4]
    at data.ElasticConnector.createIndex(ElasticConnector.scala:28) ~[candidate-retrieval.candidate-retrieval-1.0-sans-externalized.jar:na]
node {#transport#-1}{zPkzTwpJRNmzGiEM8MOQQA}{elasticsearch}{172.17.0.2:9300} not part of the cluster Cluster [elasticsearch-cluster], ignoring...
node {#transport#-1}{zPkzTwpJRNmzGiEM8MOQQA}{elasticsearch}{172.17.0.2:9300} not part of the cluster Cluster [elasticsearch-cluster], ignoring...
node {#transport#-1}{zPkzTwpJRNmzGiEM8MOQQA}{elasticsearch}{172.17.0.2:9300} not part of the cluster Cluster [elasticsearch-cluster], ignoring...
```

Also, when I tried connecting from the command-line of the client docker container:

```
docker run -it --link 57b2dc1f05b3:elasticsearch <container_name> bash
```

on "elasticsearch:9200" there was no problem connecting with the elasticsearch docker.

Code snippets for support:

```
val host = "elasticsearch"
val port = 9300
val clustername = "elasticsearch"
Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", clustername).build()
val client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(host), port))
```